# adding date AND time to event calendar android

Tags: android

I am creating event in my calendar to my  android device. Below is the code [which I have searched through internet].

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    long startTime = getMilliSeconds(startDate) + 1000 * 60 * 60;  
    long endTime = getMilliSeconds(endDate) + 1000 * 60 * 60 *2; 

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime );
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
    intent.putExtra("title", ""+mytitle);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public long getMilliSeconds(String date) throws ParseException{
    Date dateSample = null ; 
    try {  
        //2013-12-28 23:30:00
        SimpleDateFormat formatter ;       
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateSample = (Date) formatter.parse(date);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return dateSample.getTime();
}
```

it is working fine but the time is not displaying when creating the event. only the month day and year are displaying. Now, I want to make the time to show while creating the event. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why would an all day event have a start time? its all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set it to all day:

```
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
```

If you remove that line, it should work.

Comment: hi @flx. thank you for your answer. can I also ask what does "1000 * 60 * 60 *2" do? your answer solved my problem but unfortunately, I am not getting the right time. I got right date, but not the time. thanks

Comment: `1000 * 60 * 60` is one hour in milliseconds. `*2` makes it two hours.